# Hive installation

Tags: hadoop, hive

After we install hive-3.2.1 on Hadoop-3.3.0 in Ubuntu, we start the hive services. I am not sure how HIVE identifies hadoop services though we don't give anything related to Hadoop in the HIVE setup process. Does HIVE identify hadoop by the means of HADOOP_HOME  environment variable defined in .bashrc file ?

Can someone please confirm my understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hive uses `HADOOP_HOME/conf` to discover the cluster, which could be specified in `hive-env.sh`